# Xubuntu 22.04 not saving desktop settings in persistence

Tags: xubuntu, themes, settings, desktop-background, persistence

I'm using xubuntu 22.04.2 with live persistence and it's working fine except for a few things.
Does anyone know why xubuntu live persistence doesn't save some settings? Mainly desktop environment such as wallpapers, dpi scaling

It works just fine saving files etc.. I tried other distro such as mint with live persistence and it saves desktop settings on my next boot. But with xubuntu my desktop goes back to initial default wallpapers and fonts scaling.

I appreciate if anyone knows how to fix this.

This is a copy of a question someone else has asked on reddit and since I face the exact same issue I am posting it here.Persistence was created using Ventoy.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I could not download Xubuntu 22.04.2 but downloaded the current **Xubuntu 22.04.3** iso file and made a persistent live drive with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) using the 'dus-iso2usb' method. After tweaking, shutdown and cold boot the new wallpaper and new font settings were preserved. - So maybe you should save your personal files and make a new persistent live drive with Xubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: I actually tried it on 22.04.3,the original poster on reddit was using 22.04.2 so I suspect it is a ventoy issue if it works on your end.Too bad because this would mean I won't be able to put multiple isos on the usb drive with the tool you used.

Comment: That's right, mkusb makes only one persistent live system on the USB pendrive. Maybe the problem you notice is caused by some tweak to make it possible to have several persistent live systems on the same drive.